# How do I change the date in Google Cloud Container-Optimized OS?

Tags: linux, bash, date, time, google-cloud-platform

I try to set date:

```
sudo date -s "28 OCT 2018 15:00:00"
```

but before I need to disable NTP

```
timedatectl set-ntp false
```

Google Cloud Container-Optimized OS doesn't have timedatectl util

```
-bash: timedatectl: command not found
```

But which util is return my set up time to ntp time ? How to set other date via ssh in Google Cloud Container-Optimized OS ? Pls help!

Answer (score 2):

The default time zone of Container-Optimized OS is UTC0. Create a symbolic link to your desired time zone as in the following example: check official docs [Changing the time zone](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#changing_the_time_zone)

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific /etc/localtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable NTP with

```
sudo systemctl stop ntp 
sudo systemctl disable ntp
```

Expected output:

```
ntp.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable ntp
```

To check:

```
systemctl is-enabled ntp
```

Expected output:

```
ntp.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install is-enabled ntp disabled
```

By default, the NTP server is pointing to either [metadata.google or metadata.google.internal in order to get the correct time](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instances#configure_ntp_for_your_instances). After disabling NTP, you can just change the date or time with

```
sudo date
```

Answer (score 0):

write for stop the servive by a moment.

```
service ntpd stop
```

for permanent stop:

```
service ntpd disable
```

Regards